# Defining properties of an object returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to create a master object that'll hold the data for my program that looks like this:

```
var state;
var init = function() {
    state = {
        runInfo: { //object that'll hold manufacturing info - run, desired price, servings/container
            price: null,
            containers: null,
            servings: null
        },
        formula: [],
        totalsServing: [],
        totalsBottle: [],
        totalsRun: []
    };
};
```

I'm trying to set the properties of the runInfo object w/in the state object with the following function:

```
manufacturingInfo = function(price, containers, servings) {
        state.runInfo.price = price;
        state.runInfo.containers = containers;
        state.runInfo.servings = servings;
};
```

When I test the function like this:

```
init();
console.log(manufacturingInfo(10, 500, 30));
```

it returns 'undefined.'

Not sure why.

Comment: You need a [`return` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) inside `manufacturingInfo`.

Comment: Are you trying to call the method? It has no return value. Are you trying to use the method to construct an object? You haven't used the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `manufacturingInfo` does not `return` something, so the value of the invocation is *undefined*, however it does make changes to `state`, so maybe you really wanted to

```
init();
manufacturingInfo(10, 500, 30);
console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

That function doesn't return anything. It is in fact running the function successfully. But because you don't have a return statement the return value will be `undefined`.

To change that put a `return` statement in your function.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect it to return?

```
manufacturingInfo = function(price, containers, servings) {
    state.runInfo.price = price;
    state.runInfo.containers = containers;
    state.runInfo.servings = servings;


    return state.runInfo; // anything here you want the function to report
};
```